# Users and groups for NetBeans and Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, netbeans, rights

I'm trying to work with Laravel 5 on NetBeans.
Now, I'm trying to `var_dump` through Laravel 5 to understand how the application works, and I keep getting 500 errors when I have even a simple syntax error in my code, and it doesn't output the error log like normally. From what I understand by research is that it's caused by Laravel not being able to write into `/storage/` folder in Laravel.
I created a new group `netbeans` and added `www-data` user to it, so right now I'm trying to figure out how do you install it so that Laravel 5 and NetBeans could 'recognize' each other. Right now I have NetBeans installed with `apt-get install`, and now that I've changed the Laravel 5 project rights with:
`chown -R www-data:netbeans laravel5/`
Now I can't access Laravel's project files with NetBeans because of right issues. All this is sort of confusing to me, so my question is:

How do I properly setup NetBeans and Laravel so I could edit my Laravel project folders files **and** somehow have Laravel access `/storage/` folder inside Laravel, so I would not see 500 error and a blank page on every syntax error I make?

P.S: I tried to be as precise and explanatory as I could be

Answer (score 1):

Check write permissions on storage folder!

Try:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 storage/
```

(i known that 777 is a bad thing to do, only do this to test).

After reading [enter link description here](http://this) it could also be a problem of permissions to write to the log folder. See the last comment from **shiny**

Comment: well I've tried it, and it still outputs a 500 Server Error whenever I do an error in the code. I'll still search upon that later, right now I just want to figure out what is the deal with the users and to set them up to sync

Comment: did you set APP_DEBUG in .env to true

Comment: I aslo edited my answer with info on 500 error because of permissions to the log folder

Comment: I tried what you suggested with the 777 for the whole project folder. And I set APP_DEBUG to true in `env/app.php`, I still get 500 when I do an error in my code